# Get binded ViewHolder's positions scope

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to get range of 'alive' ViewHolders. There is my not working solution.

```
class NotesRvAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteDateViewHolder> {

    private var lastBindPosition = 0
    private var lastUnbindPosition = 10

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteDateViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...
        onScopeChanged()
    }

    fun onScopeChanged() {
        var maxPosition = 0
        var minPosition = 0
        if(lastBindPosition > lastUnbindPosition) {
            maxPosition = lastBindPosition
            minPosition = lastUnbindPosition
        } else {
            maxPosition = lastUnbindPosition
            minPosition = lastBindPosition
        }
        scopeListener.onChanged(NotesRequest(maxPosition, minPosition))
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: NoteDateViewHolder) {
        lastUnbindPosition = holder.adapterPosition
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
    }

}
```

As `onBindViewHolder(...)` and `onViewDetachedFromWindow(...)` called in shuffled order. And it is not the only problem :)

Any ideas to get 'alive' position's scope? LayoutManager can provide only first/last *visible* items, not 'bound'.

Comment: Not Java? Is this net ?

Comment: @isnotmenow it is Kotlin. Great JVM language.